# appframework/phonegap scroll is not working on android

Tags: android, cordova, appframework

I'm developing a phonegap application for both iOs and Android platform.

I'm using AppFramework by Intel (ex. jqMobi) and it works like a charm in iOs, it works good also on android, the only thing is that the scrolling is not working in Android 2.3.6 and I can't figure out why. I don't know if it works in most recent version of Android on real device, it's not working there too in the emulator.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion...

Comment: I find out that when the app is launched if the panel has content it will be create a div with class=jqmScrollPanel, but this div is not created when I dinamically insert content from MVC template... Now i'm going to insert content in that div and it seems to work, but I think that there is a better way to do that. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

On Android 2.3.5 & 2.3.6, JQM's header and footer scroll with document and then reposition (back to top and bottom) after scrolling has stopped. This happens when header and footer are set to data-position="fixed".

It appears that these versions of android have buggy CSS implementations of {position:fixed;} and therefore JQM's behavior appears erratic when compared to other adjacent Android versions.

Comment: We've noticed a similar problem with 2.36. I'm using JQ but not JQM and fixed position isn't in the equation.